# oracle regex_like function failing in java

Tags: java, regex, oracle, jdbctemplate

I do have one query where I need to use regex_like(user_id,'^.+EMP\d?$').
It is perfectly working fine from my SQLDeveloper and giving me the desired result.

But when I am firing this query through jdbcTemplate in java,
I am getting compile time error: `Invalid escape sequence (valid ones are \b \t \n \f \r \" \' \
 \ )` for below line.

`public static final String USER_IDENTIFIER = '^.+EMP\d?$'`

To handle this I added one more backslash in my regular expression as
`'^.+EMP\\d?$'`. But this is not giving me desired result. In fact, this is not giving me any result.

How can I solve this?

Any leads will be appreciated.

P.S: There is some problem in posting question is I am adding regex as a tag, So couldn't add it.

Comment: Can you add sample data and db version number ?

Comment: I don't know Java, but on the face of it, it seems that it doesn't recognize the single-quotes as marking literal strings. Perhaps Java uses **double** quotes to enclose strings? Don't worry about what Oracle uses; Oracle only needs the string (if you pass in USER_IDENTIFIER as a bind variable), it doesn't need the single-quotes as part of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d` is a character class for digits.  How about trying this?

```
'^.+EMP[0-9]?$'
```

Also, regular expressions match anywhere in the string, so `^.+` is pretty redundant.  I am guessing that this is sufficient:

```
'EMP[0-9]?$'
```

But this is almost certainly equivalent to your expression:

```
'.EMP[0-9]?$'
```

If you are using `.` to avoid newlines, then (of course) your original is correct and concise.

Answer (score 1):

In java, an escape sequence is a backslash character followed by a letter, e.g. `\n` is the escape sequence for a newline. Hence java thinks `\d` is meant to be an escape sequence. In order to tell java that it is not an escape sequence, you need to write `\\d`. The *javadoc* for class `java.util.regex.Pattern` explains this.

Of-course Oracle SQL is not java and hence in SQL, `\d` is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting java with a single quote is for a single char only.

Here's a functioning jdbc example where you can see the setString with the regex.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE","klrice","klrice");
        PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(
                  "select * from user_tables " +
                   "where  REGEXP_LIKE(table_name,?)    ");

        stmt.setString(1, "^.+EMP\\d?$");  // the string

        ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
        while( rset.next() ) {
            System.out.println(rset.getString(1));

        }
```